# Tunnel all traffic over HTTP

Tags: macos, network, proxy

I often end up in a situation where I connect via public Wi-Fi connection, and it's severely crippled (HTTP only, no SSH, no SMTP).

I want to set up some kind of HTTP tunnel for all traffic in the system (OSX) and bypass the restriction. I have a bunch of Linux boxes on AWS that can host the server-side bit.

What are my options?

Comment: I first tried running SSH on port 80.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. But I would setup server-side terminal web app. So you can have terminal access to all of your servers, at least.